# MediaPlayer App is crashing when i try to run

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner in android development and tried to create a simple mediaplayer app which plays media from local source.

But it's crashing when i try to open it.

This is my java code.

```
package com.example.media;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button play,pause;
    SeekBar s;
    MediaPlayer m;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        m=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.live);

        play=findViewById(R.id.button3);
        pause=findViewById(R.id.button4);
        s.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        s.setMax(m.getDuration());
        s.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(fromUser)m.seekTo(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m.start();
            }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m.pause();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to learn how to debug first https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: Paste the detail exception of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the seekbar object instead of calling the findViewById method.

So just replace the dot with equal sign :

```
  s=findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
```